# sql server 2012 memory leak

Tags: sql-server, memory-leaks, vb6

I'm using VB6 with ADODB connection to connect to sql server 2012 database and execute queries on the database, I'm facing memory leak where I see that memory usage does not decrease after query finished even after I terminate my program the memory usage dose not decrease.

Below is my code:

```
Public adoCon As New ADODB.Connection
```

Public serverName As String, databaseName As String, tableName As String
Public sqlCmd As String

Public Sub adodb_Connect()

```
If Tenzfrm.adoCon.State = adStateOpen Then Tenzfrm.adoCon.Close
serverName = Tenzfrm.server_Name.Text
databaseName = Tenzfrm.database_Name.Text
Tenzfrm.adoCon.Provider = "sqloledb"
Tenzfrm.adoCon.Properties("Data Source").Value = serverName
Tenzfrm.adoCon.Properties("Initial Catalog").Value = databaseName
Tenzfrm.adoCon.Properties("Integrated Security").Value = "SSPI"
Tenzfrm.adoCon.CommandTimeout = 0
Tenzfrm.adoCon.Open
```

End Sub

Public Sub adodb_Close()

```
If Tenzfrm.adoCon.State = adStateOpen Then Tenzfrm.adoCon.Close
Set Tenzfrm.adoCon = Nothing
```

End Sub

```
Private Sub appHourlySTS_Click()

Call adodb_Connect
proccess.Caption = "Preparing tables !"
proBar2.Width = 2 * proBar1.Width / 100
sqlCmd = "IF EXISTS(SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp') DROP TABLE Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp;"
adoCon.Execute (sqlCmd)
sqlCmd = "DECLARE @sqlCmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp](';"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "SELECT @sqlCmd+='['+Headers+'] FLOAT,' FROM [dbo].[Tenz_colReg];"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "SET @sqlCmd=LEFT(@sqlCmd,LEN(@sqlCmd)-1)+')';"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "EXEC(@sqlCmd);"
adoCon.Execute (sqlCmd)
sqlCmd = "ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp] ALTER COLUMN [Date] VARCHAR(23);"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp] ALTER COLUMN [Time] VARCHAR(10);"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp] ALTER COLUMN [NE Name] VARCHAR(15);"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp] ALTER COLUMN [Cell Name] VARCHAR(64);"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp] ALTER COLUMN [CI] VARCHAR(64);"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp] ALTER COLUMN [LAC] VARCHAR(10);"
adoCon.Execute (sqlCmd)
proccess.Caption = "Appending statistics to 'Tenz_STS_Cell_Hourly' table from CS1 !"
proBar2.Width = 5 * proBar1.Width / 100
sqlCmd = "DECLARE @sqlCmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp] '; "
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "DECLARE @sc NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "SELECT @sc+='['+Name+']=[dbo].[Tenz_CS1].['+Name+'],' FROM syscolumns WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'U' AND [Name] = 'Tenz_CS1') AND ([Name]='Date' OR [Name]='Time' OR [Name]='Cell Name' OR [Name]='NE Name' OR [Name]='CI' OR [Name]='LAC');"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "SELECT @sc+='['+Name+']=CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT,[dbo].[Tenz_CS1].['+Name+']) IS NULL THEN ''0'' ELSE [dbo].[Tenz_CS1].['+Name+'] END,' FROM syscolumns WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'U' AND [Name] = 'Tenz_CS1') AND [Name]<>'Date' AND [Name]<>'Time' AND [Name]<>'Cell Name' AND [Name]<>'NE Name' AND [Name]<>'CI' AND [Name]<>'LAC';"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "SET @sc=LEFT(@sc,LEN(@sc)-1);"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "DECLARE @dc NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''; "
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "SELECT @dc+='['+Name+'],' FROM syscolumns WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'U' AND [Name] = 'Tenz_CS1') AND ([Name]='Date' OR [Name]='Time' OR [Name]='Cell Name' OR [Name]='NE Name' OR [Name]='CI' OR [Name]='LAC');"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "SELECT @dc+='['+Name+'],' FROM syscolumns WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'U' AND [Name] = 'Tenz_CS1') AND [Name]<>'Date' AND [Name]<>'Time' AND [Name]<>'Cell Name' AND [Name]<>'NE Name' AND [Name]<>'CI' AND [Name]<>'LAC';"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "SET @dc=LEFT(@dc,LEN(@dc)-1);"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "SET @sqlCmd+='('+@dc+') SELECT '+@sc+' FROM [dbo].[Tenz_CS1]';"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCmd;"
adoCon.Execute (sqlCmd)
proccess.Caption = "Appending statistics to 'Tenz_STS_Cell_Hourly' from CS2 !"
proBar2.Width = 35 * proBar1.Width / 100
sqlCmd = "DECLARE @sqlCmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'MERGE INTO [dbo].[Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp] USING [dbo].[Tenz_CS2] ON [dbo].[Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp].Date = [dbo].[Tenz_CS2].Date AND [dbo].[Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp].Time = [dbo].[Tenz_CS2].Time AND [dbo].[Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp].[Cell Name] = [dbo].[Tenz_CS2].[Cell Name] WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ';"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "DECLARE @sc NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "SELECT @sc+='['+Name+']=CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT,[dbo].[Tenz_CS2].['+Name+']) IS NULL THEN ''0'' ELSE [dbo].[Tenz_CS2].['+Name+'] END,' FROM syscolumns WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'U' AND [Name] = 'Tenz_CS2') AND [Name]<>'Date' AND [Name]<>'Time' AND [Name]<>'Cell Name' AND [Name]<>'NE Name' AND [Name]<>'CI' AND [Name]<>'LAC';"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "SET @sc=LEFT(@sc,LEN(@sc)-1)+';';"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "SET @sqlCmd+=@sc;"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCmd;"
adoCon.Execute (sqlCmd)
proccess.Caption = "Appending statistics to 'Tenz_STS_Cell_Hourly' from PS1 !"
proBar2.Width = 50 * proBar1.Width / 100
sqlCmd = "DECLARE @sqlCmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'MERGE INTO [dbo].[Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp] USING [dbo].[Tenz_PS1] ON [dbo].[Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp].Date = [dbo].[Tenz_PS1].Date AND [dbo].[Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp].Time = [dbo].[Tenz_PS1].Time AND [dbo].[Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp].[Cell Name] = [dbo].[Tenz_PS1].[Cell Name] WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ';"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "DECLARE @sc NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "SELECT @sc+='['+Name+']=CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT,[dbo].[Tenz_PS1].['+Name+']) IS NULL THEN ''0'' ELSE [dbo].[Tenz_PS1].['+Name+'] END,' FROM syscolumns WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'U' AND [Name] = 'Tenz_PS1') AND [Name]<>'Date' AND [Name]<>'Time' AND [Name]<>'Cell Name' AND [Name]<>'NE Name' AND [Name]<>'CI' AND [Name]<>'LAC';"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "SET @sc=LEFT(@sc,LEN(@sc)-1)+';';"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "SET @sqlCmd+=@sc;"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCmd;"
adoCon.Execute (sqlCmd)
proccess.Caption = "Appending statistics to 'Tenz_STS_Cell_Hourly' from PS2 !"
proBar2.Width = 65 * proBar1.Width / 100
sqlCmd = "DECLARE @sqlCmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'MERGE INTO [dbo].[Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp] USING [dbo].[Tenz_PS2] ON [dbo].[Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp].Date = [dbo].[Tenz_PS2].Date AND [dbo].[Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp].Time = [dbo].[Tenz_PS2].Time AND [dbo].[Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp].[Cell Name] = [dbo].[Tenz_PS2].[Cell Name] WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ';"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "DECLARE @sc NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "SELECT @sc+='['+Name+']=CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT,[dbo].[Tenz_PS2].['+Name+']) IS NULL THEN ''0'' ELSE [dbo].[Tenz_PS2].['+Name+'] END,' FROM syscolumns WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'U' AND [Name] = 'Tenz_PS2') AND [Name]<>'Date' AND [Name]<>'Time' AND [Name]<>'Cell Name' AND [Name]<>'NE Name' AND [Name]<>'CI' AND [Name]<>'LAC';"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "SET @sc=LEFT(@sc,LEN(@sc)-1)+';';"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "SET @sqlCmd+=@sc;"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCmd;"
adoCon.Execute (sqlCmd)
proccess.Caption = "Finishing !"
proBar2.Width = 80 * proBar1.Width / 100
sqlCmd = "DECLARE @sqlCmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly] '"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "DECLARE @sc NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''; "
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "SELECT @sc+='['+Name+'],' FROM syscolumns WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE type = 'U' AND [Name] = 'Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly');"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "SET @sc=LEFT(@sc,LEN(@sc)-1);"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "SET @sqlCmd+='('+@sc+') SELECT '+@sc+'FROM [dbo].[Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp]';"
sqlCmd = sqlCmd & "EXEC sp_executesql @sqlCmd;"
adoCon.Execute (sqlCmd)
proBar2.Width = 100 * proBar1.Width / 100
MsgBox ("Statistics appended to 'Tenz_STS_Cell_Hourly' successfully !")
proBar2.Width = 0
proccess.Caption = "Idle ! "
sqlCmd = "IF EXISTS(SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp') DROP TABLE Tenz_Cell_STS_Hourly_Temp;"
adoCon.Execute (sqlCmd)
Call adodb_Close
```

End Sub

Comment: Can you just output the generated SQLCMD text, so it is easier to see the SQL generated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Seeing High Memory Usage In SQL Server 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132330/seeing-high-memory-usage-in-sql-server-2012)

Comment: Just to be clear, are you talking about memory usage on a client, or on the SQL Server host?

Comment: Hi Dominic Zukiewicz, 

the columns in my tables is about 200 columns, so it's hard to put the generated SQLCMD also the column names is too long.

Comment: Hello DMason, Actually I did not get your question, but I'm talking about the memory usage of my PC where sql server is installed.

hope that's helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same problem. SQL server will always use as much memory as you allow it to. You have to set a limit.

[SSMS not releasing system memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661613/ssms-not-releasing-system-memory/24661734#24661734)
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47431/why-is-sql-server-consuming-more-server-memory

Right click on the server in SSMS and select properties. In the memory tab set the Maximum server memory option to limit SQLs memory usage.

[image]

Comment: I solved the issue as you said by limiting the memory usage of SQL SERVER, on the other hand it's still not releasing the memory that it's limited for SQL SERVER even if you termination, 

what ever my PC is not experience slow performance (bottle neck), thanks allot.